# How can I get the Arguments to a function (in a non-lossy way) with flow?

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

In the trivial case it appears doable, but then I run into issues with spread syntax, that I don't run into without it.

Here's a minimal repro with my stab at this:

```js
// @flow

declare function arguments<A>((A) => any): [A & A]
type Arguments<T> = $Call<typeof arguments, T>

type GetUserInfoArgs = {| user_id: number |};
type GetUserInfo = (GetUserInfoArgs) => { first_name: string, last_name: string };
type DerivedArg = $ElementType<Arguments<GetUserInfo>, 0>; // Should be the same as `GetUserInfoArgs`

/**
 * Using DerivedArg:
 * - `a` fails type checking as expected
 * - `b` does NOT fail type checking :( 
 */
const a: DerivedArg = { foo: 'bar' };
const b: {| ...DerivedArg |} = { foo: 'bar' };

/**
 * Using GetUserInfoArgs:
 * - `c` fails type checking as expected
 * - `d` fails type checking as expected 
 */
const c: GetUserInfoArgs = { foo: 'bar' };
const d: {| ...GetUserInfoArgs |} = { foo: 'bar' };
```

**[Link to repl](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX1gHNkBbEVDAZwB4BBAPgApHaBKeAXnoNQE9WAXPADateADJ4tALoAoDLwAOCWjGJkKNACrcO8ACQBhKBAjUFynIgJrS5KgBp4O2fKUIA4iAwBVSiBgASVREHFVCSk54AG8AH3hkfxgAfSxgIVRSACMA+FiAXwBuN2V4L18k4NCoxnK-AKqwtUp2LhikLBhKDGTUKDIhbpgsVEInaG7e-pBBjGHR+CKShAARAKwANxBgcKj9AFEIEA0MLXc6WxOaOsqQnHonAAZ6QvgAejf4AGUACxxkCDAeA5eAYH4ISjTAiRAAGNwad3ClBhrjeACo0bJ4Gj4H4RoR4GthlsdmoBFicQBaeAwqAwpBQLAQSIWBBgcFgADW+Oh8BAAA9lJhthT4NSYVl6cAcCBIgA5ADyWgZTNB7ng7PA3IWAkY8Apb1kYDw3QIQiJm22uz00SQOBwQgA5FlYI7FsVjahTVkhHF4AA6QMWkm7ApRW2hB3wZ2u92ojGivELeFBRHNcnYsU0sD0xCM5lq0qark8qCRAVCjAizPi4C5-Ms9XF7UEst8wXgKtAg1Gk0YDVCFONJHhu1RmMwN1LT2m9IxeKB-1DtMRPL5UeRp0uyfu+B7-fwIA)**

(fwiw using flown's `Arguments` produces [the same error](https://github.com/lttb/flown/issues/19))

I'm looking for a way to get `DerivedArg` that passes test case b. (My actual use case is more fancy, but this is a minimal repro of the blocker I'm running into)

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7709 may be related...